# Variable values changing between requests in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Consider the following code:

```
<cfset local.quiz = getQuiz(param1,param2) />
<!--- returns a struct that has a key called unlock_at --->
<cfset quiz.unlock_at = (quiz.unlock_at EQ '') ? '' : DateConvert('utc2Local',createODBCDateTime(ISOToDateTime(quiz.unlock_at))) />
```

This is how I origionally wrote my code. When I called the page that ran this code multiple times, the value of `quiz.unlock_at` was changing in 6 hour increments (the amount of adjustment in the function). When I say increments I mean first page load the time was say 12:00. The next page load 6:00, the next page load 00:00 and so on. The physical time was changing each time. I changed the code to this:

```
<cfset local.unlock_at = (quiz.unlock_at EQ '') ? '' : DateConvert('utc2Local',createODBCDateTime(ISOToDateTime('#quiz.unlock_at#'))) />
```

The first thing is I'm storing the value in a local variable and no longer updating the existing struct. The second thing is I am passing in the date to the function as a string and not as the variable. I wasn't sure how it was getting altered. In either case:

How the heck was this changing between requests. I didn't think these variables lives between page requests. All of this code is inside a function that lives inside a CFC. What of any of that data is persistent. I called the page a few times and watched the dates change then opened a NEW browser and the data was altered too. How is that possible?

Is this a scoping issue, a data persistence issue with components? Threw me for a loop and I still and not sure what happened and until I do I'm afraid I may have other issues.

Comment: The part that looks wrong to me is that this, `<cfset quiz.unlock_at `, should be this, `<cfset local.quiz.unlock_at `.

Comment: You only need `local` the first time you create a locally scoped variable in CF. You don't need it the second time. I just tried adding `local.quiz.unlock_at` and the data changed the same. Somehow the value assigned to `quiz.unlock_at` is the data it's using in the next page request.

Comment: True, technically the declaration is only needed once. However, including scope when referencing variables is still a good practice IMO, for increased readability. It also helps reduce unexpected results in the case of ambiguous variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Grrr...

The function `getQuiz` created a struct and then cached it. The reason being is that it's an API call and I don't want to have to run an API call every time for data that doesn't change that often. So what I was doing was:

```
<cffunction name="getQuiz">
<cfset local.variable = {} />
<!--- Load Sturct Data --->
<!--- CachePut the variable --->
<cfreturn variable />
</cffunction>
<cfset quiz = getQuiz() />
<cfset quiz.unlock_at = 1 />
<!--- At this point I have actually edited a direct reference to the cached variable quiz even though I tried locally scoping it etc.
```

So, apparently returning a struct is the same as passing a struct into a function, i.e. it passes the struct by reference not by value. For some reason I thought returning a struct didn't return it as a reference, but it makes sense because that is the way CF passes values between functions.

Comment: It sounds like there is a little more to it  ... probably something to do with the "caching" mentioned in the comments? If you are truly a) creating a brand new structure each time b) properly localizing the variable and c) populating it with *simple* values - then there should not be an issue.

Comment: I understand, but if you cache a struct and then return that same struct out of the function and then edit that struct, you are editing the cached copy. I was under the assumption that when cached, the data (complex or simple) was stored as a value not by reference (essentially duplicating the data), even if it is a complex type, this is not the case. I'll need to get in the habit of duplicating things when caching them.